# Django add dynamic fields with dynamic name attributes to front end and then insert it to Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a Model which consists of almost 500+ fields. I want to take data through the front-end Form. But the issue is I can’t display all the 500 fields.

what I want is I will add the fields which I need. like on day-1 I will add 3 fields. food = 230 , petrol = 500, rent = 700. on the second day, fields may vary. I can add 20 fields on the second day. on the third day data may be of different fields. like petrol = 200, cement= 5000 , steel = 100 etc etc and so on!

Simple Solution is: I displayed all fields in HTML and submitted it to view and received in View function through Post Request! and then save() . But i want it to be dynamic!

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        print("this is post")
        # print()
        food_expense=request.POST['food']
        petrol_expense=request.POST['petrol']
        easyload_expense=request.POST['easyload']
        labour_expense = request.POST['labour']
        equipments_expense = request.POST['equipments']
        rent_expense = request.POST['rent']
        cement_expense = request.POST['cement']
        steel_expense = request.POST['steel']
        other1_expense = request.POST['other1']
        other2_expense = request.POST['other2']
        other3_expense = request.POST['other3']
        ..... .... fields upto 500+ 
        # expense_paidby = request.POST['paid_by']
        expense_paidby_id = request.POST['paid_by']
        paidby= PaidBy.objects.get(id=expense_paidby_id)
        # expense_paidby = PaidBy.objects.get(name__icontains = request.POST['paid_by'])
        projectname_id= request.POST['pname']
        project_in_which_expenses_made=ProjectName.objects.get(id=projectname_id)
        # project_in_which_expenses_made = request.POST['project_name']
        date = request.POST['date']
        # total = food_expense+petrol_expense+easyload_expense+labour_expense+equipments_expense+rent_expense
        # print(petrol_expense, projectname_id , project_in_which_expenses_made)
        inst= ProjectExpenses(food=food_expense,petrol=petrol_expense,easyload=easyload_expense ,labour=labour_expense ,
                              equipments=equipments_expense ,rent=rent_expense,cement=cement_expense,steel=steel_expense,
                              other1=other1_expense, other2=other2_expense, other3=other3_expense, date_of_expense=date, PaidByName=paidby,
                              expenses_in_project = project_in_which_expenses_made)
        #in query i will have 500 fields.
        inst.save()
```

what I want is how I can create dynamic input fields with name attributes as I have in the database.

how should I create these fields dynamically in the front end and then how I will handle it in view function instead of writing all 500+ fields through “value = request. post[“500+ fields line by line”]” means how I can handle it dynamically only those fields which come to view function. and then save it to DB.

data will only insert in selected fields all remaining will be zero by default.

I will appreciate forum Help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question right. Perhaps a more minimal working example would clarify.

But, have you tried using [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms), such as CreateView?

You can dynamically create input forms and handling based on your model definition by adding a CreateView to your urlpatterns.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import ProjectExpenses
urlpatterns += [path("new-project-expense", CreateView.as_view(model=ProjectExpenses, fields="__all__"))]
```

You can configure the "fields" argument to be a selection of your 500 model fields.